# What is the meaning of (Paean) in the title of Ed Sheeran's "How Would You Feel (Paean)"?

Tags: pop, song-title

I've been wondering about the purpose of the (Paean) in Ed Sheeran's "How Would You Feel (Paean)" title.

I know paean means `a song of praise or triumph` but what purpose does it serve in the song's title? This is the first song I've seen have something like this. Does adding it there serve have some kind of meaning, or is it just to label it as a song of praise?

I'm inclined to believe it's just a label, but if so, why? Other songs don't go around labeling themselves "Song Title (Sad)" or "Song Title (Happy)", so why did Ed do it here?

Comment: Ed Sheeran's wife's middle name is Pæan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just to label it. It is just personal choice of whether to use it or not. Usually people do not put these labels at the end of the song but you can if you want to. People also sometimes use parenthesis at the end of their songs for things such as the hook of the song, such as Kendrick Lamar - Swimming Pools (Drank) or Eifel 65 - Blue (Da Ba Dee) so that people can find the song more easily if they were searching for it. I suppose that Ed Sheeran just put it in because he wanted people to know that the song is a paean, or so that they could find it more easily if they were searching for a paean with matching lyrics.